# How to call a PHP function with javascript for star-rating bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am strugling over a couple of day's getting this script to run. Maybe my problem is simple to solve, but please help me. The idea is a user can rate a song from an artist using bootstrap en star-rating plugin from http://plugins.krajee.com.

[image: rating-star script]

Javascript that requested to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#input-id').on('rating.change', function(event, value, caption) {
            console.log(value);
            console.log(caption);
        });
    ();});
</script>
```

The HTML input on the page is:

```
<input id="input-id" type="number" class="rating" min=1 max=5 step=1 data-size="xs" data-rtl="false">
```

PHP function to get the rating into the database

```
$rate = $oArtists->SaveSongRating($_POST["song_id"],$_POST["rate"],$userid);
```

My question:
How can I combine the Javascript with the PHP function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/myScript.php',
         data: {
             song_id: 123,
             rate: 5
         },
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
              alert(output);
         }
});
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, You request an ajax call but i don't understand where is the php function SveSongRating in the class file oArtist? and the Song_id and rate number should come from the post?

Comment: I have made a workaround by using a submit button and call the function by getting the if($_POST['rate']. it works fine for now.